# How to pass arguments to entrypoint in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose

I use this image: dperson/samba

The image is defining its own entrypoint and I do not want to override it.

I need to pass arguments to the entrypoint, easy with docker only:

```
docker run ... dperson/samba arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But how to do it with docker_compose.yml ?

Right now I use as a workaround:

```
command: samba.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But it is not satisfying as I force the redefinition of the entrypoint.

Answer (score 253):

The `command` clause does work [as @Karthik says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843513/4575793).

As a simple example, the following service will have a `-inMemory` added to its `ENTRYPOINT` when `docker-compose up` is run.

```
version: '2'
services:
  local-dynamo:
    build: local-dynamo
    image: spud/dynamo
    command: -inMemory
```

Comment: Is there documentation on this? I can't seem to find any reference to a command clause on a docker-compose service.

Comment: I get `Error parsing commandline arguments: unknown short flag '-w'` when I supply `command:
      - -web.config.file=web.yml`

Comment: Here are the docs for `command`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command

Answer (score 108):

Whatever is specified in the `command` in docker-compose.yml should get appended to the `entrypoint` defined in the Dockerfile, provided `entrypoint` is defined in [exec form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904974/what-are-shell-form-and-exec-form) in the Dockerfile:

`ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]`

If the EntryPoint is defined in shell form (e.g., `ENTRYPOINT executable param1 param2`), then any CMD arguments will be ignored.

Comment: How about some examples. What is "exec form" ?

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]` (exec form, preferred)
`ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2` (shell form)

Reference: [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Comment: An example would help this answer so much.

Answer (score 51):

You can use `docker-compose run` instead of `docker-compose up` and tack the arguments on the end. For example:

```
docker-compose run dperson/samba arg1 arg2 arg3
```

If you need to connect to other docker containers, use can use `--service-ports` option:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports dperson/samba arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: sadly in swarm this is not an option

Comment: Unfortunately, that creates a container with a long name (with an ID appended) so you can't use `docker-compose logs <service>` because the service name is different (and no doubt other differences.)

Comment: So, in a multi-container application (i.e. with multiple services), how can you pass unique arguments to the individual services. For example, I want to pass the first container a file directory as input, it performs some operation, outputs something, then I want to pass that output to the next container as input. How would I do that with docker-compose? In the .yml configuration file or at runtime? The argument to the first container would be a file directory on the local host, so I could use a bind mount for that, but I am unsure of how to orchestrate the subsequent containers with arguments

Answer (score 50):

To override the default entrypoint, use [`entrypoint` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint). To pass the arguments use `command`.

Here is the example of replacing `bash` with `sh` in `ubuntu` image:

```
version: '3'
services:
  sh:
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    command: -c "ps $$(echo $$$$)"
    image: ubuntu
    tty: true
  bash:
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "ps $$(echo $$$$)"
    image: ubuntu
    tty: true
```

Here is the output:

```
$ docker-compose up   
Starting test_sh_1                ... done
Starting 020211508a29_test_bash_1 ... done
Attaching to test_sh_1, 020211508a29_test_bash_1
sh_1    |   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
sh_1    |     1 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 /bin/sh -c ps $(echo $$)
020211508a29_test_bash_1 |   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
020211508a29_test_bash_1 |     1 pts/0    Rs+    0:00 ps 1
```

Answer (score 21):

I was facing the same issue with jenkins ssh slave '[jenkinsci/ssh-slave](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/ssh-slave/dockerfile/)'. However, my case was a bit complicated because it was necessary to pass an argument which contained spaces. I've managed to do it like below (entrypoint in dockerfile is in exec form):

```
command: ["some argument with space which should be treated as one"]
```

Answer (score 13):

you can pass the args in the `command` field just like that

```
command:
  - arg1
  - arg2
```

Answer (score 2):

You also don't need to use the `command` option in `docker-compose.yml`, you can just pass them as additional bullet points in the `entrypoint` section like this:

```
    entrypoint:
      - /entrypoint.sh
      - arg1
      - arg2
```