# Changing SQL Mode on Mariadb Image with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have an issue with the official dockerized image of Mariadb.

When my applications tries to make some queries I got the following error :

> DB Error: unknown error QUERY : INSERT INTO

It seems this error comes from the SQL_MODE, which is set as follow in this image :

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,
NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I have a normal Linux Server and with mariadb installed and i don't have this STRICT_TRANS_TABLES value in my SQL_mode. And my application is working without any problem.

How can I remove the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES value in my container when I run docker-compose with my docker-compose file without the need of a custom dockerfile?

Comment: Establish a value for `strict_mode` in the `my.cnf` for that docker.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` set command: `--sql_mode=""`.
Here is an example:

```yaml
db-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: db.dockerfile
    image: example/repo:db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/db-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: your_database
    command: mysqld --sql_mode="" --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_slovenian_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;' --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - yournet
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: finally found someone with docker-compose solution to this problem.

Comment: Note that in case you're using a prebuilt image from docker hub, you can also just specify `command: --sql-mode=""` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366857/how-to-pass-arguments-to-entrypoint-in-docker-compose-yml to add to the entrypoint defined in that image.