# Always include arguments when running docker-compose run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a question regarding the passing of arguments in `docker-compose run`:

I'm using a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/DockerDemos/appstack-wpcli/blob/master/Dockerfile) that has the following entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/ bin / wp"]
CMD ["--allow-root", "--help"]
```

I need `--allow-root` to ALWAYS be included.

If I run `docker-compose run [service]`, the argument goes by default. But if I run `docker-compose run [service] option (option option ...)` I need to include the argument manually.

Have you ALWAYS include the argument? Do I need to edit Dockerfile (I'm not the author) or can I do it via docker-compose? I tried the [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366857/how-to-pass-arguments-to-entrypoint-in-docker-compose-yml), but it didn't not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

the `ENTRYPOINT` is what is run when starting the container and the `CMD` appends to entrypoint. So if you add --allow-root to entrypoint it should be enough

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/ bin / wp --allow-root"]
```

Comment: If CMD appends to the entrypoint, shouldn't it always get appended anyway? Why it is only appended when I don't add extra arguments?

Comment: Besides, I don't own the dockerfile and can't edit it.

Comment: `CMD` is something you usually override with run.... but since you know the image name, you can create own Dockerfile use the base image from that and write own ENTRYPOINT