# Override Spring active profiles with Docker Compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker image that have the following `Dockerfile` content:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV MYHOME /home/docker

ARG JAR_FILE
ENV JAR ${JAR_FILE}

COPY $JAR_FILE ${MYHOME}/$JAR_FILE

WORKDIR ${MYHOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -jar ${MYHOME}/${JAR} --spring.profiles.active=docker,foo"]
```

When I try to include this docker image in a docker compose file together with other images, I want to override Spring active profiles.

I tried using the following `docker-compose.yml` content:

```
...
my_image:
  image: my_image
  environment:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: 'docker,bar'
...
```

But when runnig the docker compose with the above configuration and looking into the container log, I found that the active profiles are:

```
...
The following profiles are active: docker,foo
...
```

In my case, how can I set the **docker,bar** profiles using docker compose?

Comment: IIRC, command line has highest priority for spring properties; you're probably best off to either change the docker file, or create another image based on it (with a new command line). Alternatively, you can try to give the same parameter again and hope it overrides the existing one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366857/how-to-pass-arguments-to-entrypoint-in-docker-compose-yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @daniu says in a comment, the `--spring.profiles.active` command-line option takes precedence over the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable.  The actual precedence listing is described in [Externalized Configuration] in the Spring Boot documentation.

On the other hand, a `docker run -e` option will take precedence over an environment variable set in the image.  So if you set `ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=...` in your image, the `docker run -e` option will work as you expect; do not include the command-line option in your application startup.

```sh
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker,foo
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/myapp.jar"] # without --spring.profiles.active option
```